# How to check if an instance name already exists

Tags: ruby, class

How can I make it so that each time a new instance of the class `User` is created, the instance will be named `user#` (#=a number), so that each user has a different number.

So that it does something like this:

```
user1 = User.new("user", "password")
user2 = User.new("other_user", "password")
user3 = User.new("other_user", "password")
...
```

But if `user1` already exists I want it so that when it creates a new user it will name it `user2` and not recreate `user1` and so on.

Comment: How do you want to access that newly created `User` object then if you don't even know its variable name?

Comment: Put all of the `User`'s in an array, so you can access them via a number?

Comment: create A `UserFactory` class that churns out instances of the `User` class and can keep track of them. You would create a new User with `my_user_factory_instance.newUser()` the `newUser` method can assign the `User` instances a serial num.

Comment: @JustinWood: Yeah, this will work. But then, the local variable is not required at all and it does not matter whether it's overwritten or not.

Answer (score 3):

Defining variables the way you think about makes it hard to read the variables later on. Imaging how you want to read the values again? You need to keep track yourself how many variables exist. And there is no need to use meta programming in this case.

A data structure that avoids this problems is an [Array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) that allow you to store elements and read them again by their position within the array:

```
users = []
users << User.new("user", "password")
users << User.new("other_user", "password")
users << User.new("other_user", "password")

users
#=> returns all users in an array

users.size
#=> returns the number of users in the array

users[0]
#=> returns the first User

users[n]
#=> returns the n User in this array
```

It looks to me like the OP wants to have (or at least doesn't care about) duplicates. But, if you want to avoid duplicates, you can check for duplicates before adding new elements like this:

```
user = User.new("other_user", "password")
users << user unless users.include?(user)
```

Or you could remove duplicates by calling `users.uniq`.

Comment: Why not `users[1]`? Please explain how this array solves the question, because to me, it looks like simply querying the array at different points.

Comment: That is a great edit. Still a question: How would you then determine whether 2 elements are the same? I could easily do this in Rails with ActiveRecord, but I am assuming this is near-vanilla ruby. (I know I am not OP, but this question intrigues me)